# The parameterized query 'select ...' expects the parameter '@parameter', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error when trying to load the page only. The error is highlighted in bold.

```
string strConnectionString = "...";
SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
string strCommandText = "SELECT NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName FROM Customer WHERE NRIC=@nric";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nric", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
cmd.Parameters["@nric"].Value = (String)Session["CustomerNRIC"];
myConnect.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The error message is:

> The parameterized query '(@nric nvarchar(100))SELECT NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName 
>   FROM C' expects the parameter '@nric', which was not supplied. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@nric nvarchar(100))SELECT NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName FROM C' expects the parameter '@nric', which was not supplied.

My Customer TABLE

> GuestID             nvarchar(max) NRIC                nvarchar(50)
>   FirstName           nvarchar(50) LastName            nvarchar(50)
>   GuestAddress        nvarchar(50) GuestTelephone      nvarchar(50) DOB 
>   nvarchar(50) Gender              nvarchar(50) Email
>   nvarchar(50)

Comment: Why so much code? Post only relevant porton. Even marc not able to format all the code

Comment: You should really narrow your code down to the actual problem lines + / - 5.

Comment: The parameterized query '(@nric nvarchar(100))SELECT NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName FROM C' expects the parameter '@nric', which was not supplied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The parameterized query '(@nric nvarchar(100))SELECT NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName FROM C' expects the parameter '@nric', which was not supplied.

Comment: Line 37:               myConnect.Open();
Line 38: 
Line 39:               SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
Line 40: 
Line 41:               if (reader.Read())

Comment: As @ Patrick Hofman said narrow your code and post only relevant lines this saves resources and makes it easy for others too

Comment: im sorry, can anyone help?

Comment: I wonder why the query from the error message does not match your query, and is not even a valid query. What is the actual DB you are using, and does the problem go away if you start using [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) properly?

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking that the value of `@nric` is `null`. In that case, the parameter is 'not specified'. If `null` is a valid value in your query, use `DBNull.Value`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@nric", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session["CustomerNRIC"]))
{
    cmd.Parameters["@nric"].Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters["@nric"].Value = Session["CustomerNRIC"];
}
```

Comment: When i added that,
An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@nric' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Yup, added your editted codes and I got back same error.
The parameterized query '(@nric nvarchar(100))SELECT NRIC,StaffName FROM Staff WHERE NRIC' expects the parameter '@nric', which was not supplied.

Comment: I guess that is another line of code since the original error contained the fields 'NRIC,Email,FirstName,LastName' and was selected from `Customer`